# Does randomSplit return a copy or a reference to the original rdd?

Tags: python, apache-spark

Suppose I have something like the code below

```
for idx in xrange(0, 10):
    train_test_split = training.randomSplit(weights=[0.75, 0.25])
    train_cv = train_test_split[0]
    test_cv = train_test_split[1]
    # scale train_cv and test_cv
```

by scaling `train_cv` and `test_cv`, will the original data be affected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### RDDs are immutable.

Therefore, it's actually not possible to 'change' an RDD only transform them. 
So, no, the original data will not be affected.

Comment: If we call an action on train_cv multiple times (please note training is not cached), would train_cv be different every time ?

Comment: @lavmudgal RDDs are evaluated following their DAG of dependencies. If the actual source of data changes, then you may see different results. This is an 'out-of-context' answer. I'd recommend you to ask a new question with your specific situation.